# How to get first record in many to many relationship using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

my model

```
 public function semesters(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Semester::class)
        ->orderBy('name', 'desc');
    }
```

my controller code

`$semesters = Auth::guard('student')->user()->semesters;`

my blade code is

`{{ dd($semesters->name) }}`

and the error is

`Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.`

my expectation is to get singal semester name in blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're facing is due to the issue you're not referring to the correct data. You can do it by doing something like this:

```
$semesters = Auth::guard('student')->user()->semesters;
$semesterName = $semesters->first()->name;
return view('your-blade-view', compact('semesterName'));
```

and then you can use `semesterName` to render the name on frontend. The code will fetch the first result and then get the name from the result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
 $semesters = Auth::guard('student')->user()->semesters;
 return view('dashboards.student.home',['semester'=>$semesters[0]['name']]);
```

**this is very simpale i also get idea from another stackovreflow question and also working for me **